# awk - how to specify field separator as binary value 0x1

Tags: awk

Is it possible to specify the separator field `FS` in binary for awk?

I have data file with ascii data fields but separated by binary delimiter `0x1`.

If it was character `'1'` it would look like this:

```
awk -F1 '/FIELD/ { print $1 }'
```

Or in script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "1" }

/FIELD/ { print $1 }
```

How can I specify `FS/F` to be `0x1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "\x01" }

/FIELD/ { print $1 }
```

See http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html.

Comment: Hm, right ... I tried that but it did not work form me originally ... until I remembered that my separator is binary 0x2 .... I thought I have problem with specifying binary separator ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '\x01' '/FIELD/ { print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

works on `mawk`, `gawk`, or `nawk` :

> ```
>  awk -F'\1' '{ … }'
> ```

`awk`s can properly decipher the octal code without needing help from the shell like

> ```
>  awk -F$'\1' '{ … }'
> ```